# Does MessagePerformanceUtils work for JMSAdapter in Blazeds?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds

I have enabled the message processing metrics for all my channels in blazeds services-config.xml . I get the metrics when i use actionscript Adapter for my destination .But , when i use a JMS Adapter for consuming messages . i get the following error

```
Error: Message is missing MPI headers.  Verify that all participants have it enabled.
    at mx.messaging.messages::MessagePerformanceUtils()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\messages\MessagePerformanceUtils.as:118]
```

All my channels are pre-configured in xml files with message processing metrics enabled  . i am not creating any dynamic channels at runtime .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but you should check if someone is setting the performance headers on your JMS message. If the message is produced outside of your system by the "participant" and pushed in  queue there is no way to extract this information on the Flex side.

The messages produced by a Flex client using metrics enabled channels and pushed to a JMS queue should have this information in the headers. If it does not work please create a working test case which can reproduce this problem and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yea, the message is produced outside the flex app by a java application and puts it in a JMS topic . Which the blazeds consumes and pushes to the flex client . In the blazeds Dev guide , its says When enabled, metrics are available to a client that received a pushed message from the server . So , i generalised it for any application which puts in jms messages ,not just flex clients .

Comment: It will work for any application only if the producers are configuring some special headers. Yes, the development guide it's a little bit misleading.